# CSS styling of product list using divs

Tags: html, css

I can do the following layout using tables, but would like to know how to achieve it using divs rather.

this is what im trying to achieve. [Product list](http://s29.postimg.org/tafqy9vd3/goal.png)
[image]

so if I use this css

```
body {
 background-color: lightblue;
}

.container {
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.productsList {
background-color: lightseagreen;    
}

.productsList .product {
   background-color: lightgreen;
   margin: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #CADFE4;
}

.productsList .product .productImage{

}
```

and this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Products list below</h2>
    <div class="productsList">
        <br />
        <div class="product">
            <div class="productImage">IMG</div>
            HEADING OF THE PRODUCT
            description of the product
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="product">
            <div class="productImage">IMG</div>
            HEADING OF THE PRODUCT
            description of the product
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="product">
            <div class="productImage">IMG</div>
            HEADING OF THE PRODUCT
            description of the product
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so container for all products and then each product div should have class of product..
I'm not quite able to get the image left and the rest of the text to the right.

Should be trivial for css pros who use divs alot.

Comment: Have you tried `float: left` on the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float: left` on `.productImage` and add a clearfix to `.product`. I would also suggest using a header element  (`<h2>`, `<h3>` etc.) for the product title.

You can also wrap your product title and description in a new div and float that. See `.productInfo`.

[**See this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/87Z5w/1/)

```
/* Clearfix */
.productsList .product::after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
}

.productsList .product .productImage{
    float: left;
}

.productsList .product .productInfo {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanksm for the response. Yeah, this seems to be what I should be using. Great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate image and text into 2 different div, something like this:

```
<div class="product">
     <div class="image">
           //your img
     </div>
     <div class="desc">
          // your desc
     </div>
</div>
```

and change the image and desc to have display: inline-block instead of display:block
if the vertical alignment is incorrect, you can add vertical-align:top to both of them. the css should be like this:

```
.product > image,
.product > desc{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

I haven't tested the code but should work if you play with it.

*I like to avoid using float...*

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to emulate a table you could use display:table and display:table-cell. As Andrew mentioned you will need to add a div for your description. Since this is a list you might want to consider marking it up as an unordered-list... see my fiddle

```
.productsList .product {
    display: table;
}
.productsList .productImage,
.productsList .productDescription {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanswedal/c4gqM/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've created a very simple version for you.

Working demo - **EDIT** http://jsfiddle.net/justnath/hLde3/1/

```
<div class="product">
     <div class="productImage">IMG</div>
     <p> HEADING OF THE PRODUCT description of the product</p>
</div>


.productsList .product {
     background-color: lightgreen;
     margin: 10px;
     border: 1px solid #CADFE4;
}
.product{
     float:left;
     display:block;
     width:980px;
}
.productsList .product .productImage{
     width:150px;
     height:150px;
     background-color:grey;
     float:left;
     margin-right:10px;
}
.productsList .product p{
     margin-left:160px;
}
```